# Bootstrap разная позиция в разных размерах

Tags: css, bootstrap

Что то не приходит ничего полезного в голову, есть два вида, условно - десктоп и моб версии, необходимо в моб версии перенести красную скнопку под все эелементы:

[image: десктоп]

[image: моб]

Текущая разметка:

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-5">
  <div class="form-group mvf-bajas-required">
   <label for="">Tipo de producto</label>
   <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
    <option value="" default>Selecciona</option>
    <option value="">Selecciona</option>
    <option value="">Selecciona</option>
    <option value="">Selecciona</option>
    <option value="">Selecciona</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Anadir</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-7">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group mvf-bajas-required">
       <label for="">Numero</label>
       <input id="" name="" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="677 761 768">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-8">
      <label>Marca los productos que deseas dar de baja:</label>
      <div class="mvf-bajas-checkbox-group">
       <input id="checkbox1" name="" type="checkbox">
       <label for="checkbox1">Television Linea 56</label>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group mvf-bajas-required">
     <label for="">Numero</label>
     <input id="" name="" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="677 761 768">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="mvf-bajas-checkbox-group">
     <input id="checkbox2" name="" type="checkbox">
     <label for="checkbox2">Television Linea 58</label>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group mvf-bajas-required">
     <label for="">Numero</label>
     <input id="" name="" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="677 761 768">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="mvf-bajas-checkbox-group">
     <input id="checkbox3" name="" type="checkbox">
     <label for="checkbox3">Television Linea 22</label>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Ничего кроме как сделать еще одну кнопку и одну скрывать в моб, другую в десктопе, в голову не лезет.

Любые светлые мысли?

Comment: Почему не сделать отступ в десктоп версии?

Comment: @Alex78191 Какой отступ?

Comment: задать margin для с помощью media query

Comment: для моб версии опустить кнопку маржином?

Comment: Да, или поднять в десктопной или опустить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить среднему блоку правый флоат на экранах шириной от 768 пикселей. У двух других блоков останется левый флоат, и они окажутся друг под другом.

```css
/* суть дела */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pull-sm-right { 
    float: right !important;
  }
}

/* для красоты */
.decorations > div {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 6px; 
}
.decorations > div:nth-of-type(1) { background: #9c6; min-height:  80px; }
.decorations > div:nth-of-type(2) { background: #69c; min-height: 200px; }
.decorations > div:nth-of-type(3) { background: #f33; min-height:  80px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row decorations">
    <div class="col-sm-5">Поле со списком</div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 pull-sm-right">Много полей</div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">Кнопка</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В принципе в том же направлении думал думал та и не дадумал, дедлайны они такие) Спасибо.